# How can I SELECT a row with MAX(value) from a derived table where the values are all calculated sums?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, group-by, greatest-n-per-group

I have tried the following code but I just get the full table with all the names and sum values instead of one row with the max value:

```
SELECT stageName, max(total_salary)
FROM (
      SELECT c.*, sum(p.dailySalary) as total_salary        
      from contender as c
      left join participant as p
      on (p.contender = c.idContender)
      group by c.idContender ) b
group by stageName;
```

```
output: 
Yellow Jesters  205
TikTok  3073
Teabags 947
Bobbleheads 11840
Reddit  1486
```

but I just need:
Bobbleheads 11840

PS: Please suggest a solution WITHOUT using desc and limit

Comment: If you are using MySQL 8.0, you can use [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions.html).

Comment: @BillKarwin could you please show me how to do it without windows functions and desc and limit?

Comment: At this point you should list the SQL features you _are_ allowed to use. I'm not going to play a guessing game.

Comment: @BillKarwin yea sure. I need to make a select query using joins, aggregate functions and basic functions like sum and max.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a solution that should work on any version of MySQL 5.x, using no ORDER BY, LIMIT, window functions, views, or CTEs.

```
SELECT a.stagename, a.total_salary
FROM (
      SELECT c.*, sum(p.dailySalary) as total_salary        
      from contender as c
      left join participant as p
      on (p.contender = c.idContender)
      group by c.idContender ) AS a
LEFT OUTER JOIN (
      SELECT c.*, sum(p.dailySalary) as total_salary        
      from contender as c
      left join participant as p
      on (p.contender = c.idContender)
      group by c.idContender ) AS b
  ON a.total_salary < b.total_salary
WHERE b.total_salary IS NULL;
```

Tested on MySQL 5.7.27.

Output:

```
+-------------+--------------+
| stagename   | total_salary |
+-------------+--------------+
| Bobbleheads |        11840 |
+-------------+--------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to top row in your resultset, you can sort and limit:

```
select c.*, sum(p.dailySalary) as total_salary        
from contender as c
left join participant as p on p.contender = c.idContender
group by c.idContender
order by total_salary desc
limit 1
```

If there is a possibility of top tie, and you want to allow it, you can use window functions:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        c.*, 
        sum(p.dailySalary) as total_salary, 
        rank() over(order by sum(p.dailySalary) desc) rn
    from contender as c
    left join participant as p on p.contender = c.idContender
    group by c.idContender
) t
where rn = 1
```

Comment: I am sorry but could you suggest a solution wihtout using desc (and windows functions) like I mentioned in my ps? Thank you so much

Comment: @mystictuff: why do you want to avoid `order by` and `limit` (as shown in the first query)? This seems like the most relevant option here (and all versions of MySQL support this).

Comment: my assignment disallows those options which is why I've been struggling with it for so long. Could you please help me out?

Comment: @mystictuff: I don't see the rationale for these constraints - and you did not express them in your original question. As far as concerned, I provided two reasonable queries that give you the results that you expect.